Using Audio in the Gemini API
I am trying to use the Gemini API using the Swift SDK but also using URLSession to process audio as inline data.
let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
let model = GenerativeModel(name: "gemini-1.5-flash", apiKey: apiKey)
let response = try await model.generateContent([
    ModelContent.Part.data(mimetype: "m4a", fileData),
    ModelContent.Part.text("Say something")
])
let text = response.text ?? "no response"
print(text)

But the only output I get is:
[GoogleGenerativeAI] Response payload: {
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "An internal error has occurred. Please retry or report in https://developers.generativeai.google/guide/troubleshooting",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}

and
internalError(underlying: GoogleGenerativeAI.RPCError(httpResponseCode: 500, message: "An internal error has occurred. Please retry or report in https://developers.generativeai.google/guide/troubleshooting", status: GoogleGenerativeAI.RPCStatus.internalError, details: []))

Where is the problem? Is it possible to use audio with Gemini?

You could try a different audio format, eg mp3, the docs
Audio
do not mention m4a/MPEG-4
